# Ignore specific string in unique constraint MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible in MySql to ignore one specific string to be allowed in unique column to be duplicated ?
When my user logs in for the first time with OAuth, im using Java ORM framework to save him in my DB with a nickname of "*()unset", save for every user who logs in first time. I want the column `nickname` to be UNIQUE but to ignore the value "*()unset" and allow it to be duplicated.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  googlesub varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  email varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  nickname varchar (16) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  enabled tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  roles VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  permissions VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (googlesub)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: use CONCAT('()unset',googlesub) that is unique

Comment: i dont want to allow 2 users to have same nickname

Comment: googlesub is a orinary key so it is unique CONCAT('()unset',googlesub) produces a unique statement or make like SO define an auto increment and add this to unnset